# Прочитать конфиг в jetty

Tags: java, java-ee, jetty

У меня есть некий конфиг .properties для бизнес-логики. Он читается по абсолютному пути приложения

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/webapps/appname/"
        "сonf.properties";
```

Но когда я через idea запускаю deploy на локальный jetty то конфиг не находится, хотя по url: "/appname/сonf.properties"  в браузере он читается. В tomcat при деплое папка с проектом вроде как копируется в ROOT и там такое чтение пропертей работает(правда там из пути надо убрать /bin/), но в jetty такого нет. Как правильно подцепить properties в проекте?

Comment: вы, кажется, забыли поставить символ "+" между директорией и названием файла.

Comment: ну это просто когда редактировал так получилось, компилятор то бы такое не пропустил) .... вообщем по прежнему у меня проблема как читать и куда положить конфиг...

Answer (score 3):

Вообщем я разобрался с проблемой и надеюсь что это поможет остальным, поэтому напишу то что нашёл:

Концепция maven - основное преимущество с maven это то что он стимулирует пользоваться стандартами, в отличии от того же ant где у разработчика несколько первых дней знакомства с проектом занимает изучения скрипта сборки. Так вот применительно к вашей ситуации у вас все ресурсы должны лежать в папке ${project_home}src/main/resources, не нужно править pom.xml чтобы объяснить maven что вы не хотите следовать его конвенциям. Используйте следующую структуру каталогов:

1. `${project_home}src/main/java` пакеты с исходным кодом
2. `${project_home}src/main/resources` пакеты с ресурсами
3. `${project_home}src/test/java` пакеты с юнит тестами, они не попадут в итоговый jar
4. `${project_home}src/test/resources` пакеты с тестовыми ресурсами, они не попадут в итоговый jar

Соответственно я раскидал все конфиги как написано выше, и тесты стали отрабатывать на тестовых ресурсах.

Для того, чтобы прочитать конфиг я делаю так:

```
@Before
public void readCfg(){
    String path = "/TestPoolConf.properties";
    url = getClass().getResource(path);
}
```

а путь к файлу извлекается так:

```
url.getPath()
```